# Rails 3.1: Auto Select Value Passed From Param to Associated Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Projects habtm Tasks

On `tasks/show.html.erb` I have `link_to "Add This Task To Project", new_project_path(:task => @task)`

This passes the @task params to the new_project_path `http://localhost:3000/projects/new?task=24`

How do I ensure the default `<select><option>` in the Project#new form is my @task.title when the `new_project_path` is accessed in this way?

===Update===

I'm using the `simple_form` gem to generate the select element

```
= simple_form_for @project do |f|

        = f.association :task, :collection => current_user.task.collect { |t| t.title }, :prompt => "Select workout"
```

Comment: What are you using to generate your `select` element? Can you provide the line(s) where you do so?

Comment: Question updated with the view to generate `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the simple_form README: "The association helper just invokes input under the hood, so all options available to :select, :radio and :check_boxes are also available to association."

So I used this (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) as a reference.

In your controller, since you received the task id through a GET request:

```
@task = Task.find(params[:task])
```

In your view:

```
= f.association :task, :collection => current_user.task.collect { |t| t.title }, :prompt => "Select workout", :selected => @task.title
```

See if that works. If not, try enclosing that last argument in curly braces to make it a hash. Let me know how it goes.